# Как умножить на определенное число каждый элемент который имеет нечетную позицию?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Например, пробовал через `index`, но что-то пошло не так:

```
s = [5, 6, 7, 3, 4, 5, 6, 4, 5, 6]

a = []
for i in s:
    m = s.index(i)
    if m % 2 == 0:
        i = i * 2
        a.append(i)
    elif s.index(i) % 2 != 0:
        a.append(i)
print(a)
```

Ожидаемый результат:

```
[10 , 6 , 14 , 3  , 8 , 5 , 6 , 8 , 5 , 12]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы умножить элементы с чётными индексами:

```
>>> L = [5, 6, 7, 3, 4, 5, 6, 4, 5, 6]
>>> L[::2] = [2*x for x in L[::2]]
>>> L
[10, 6, 14, 3, 8, 5, 12, 4, 10, 6]
```

Если не хочется в памяти половину списка создавать, можно по месту заменить:

```
for i in range(len(L)):
    if i % 2 == 0: # even index
        L[i] *= 2
```

Результат тот же.

Если на входе у вас был бы `numpy` массив, то можно было бы лаконичный `a[::2] *= 2` синтаксис использовать:

```
>>> import numpy  # $ pip install numpy
>>> a = numpy.array([5, 6, 7, 3, 4, 5, 6, 4, 5, 6])
>>> a[::2] *= 2
>>> a
array([10,  6, 14,  3,  8,  5, 12,  4, 10,  6])
```

Answer (score 4):

Можно вот так:

```
In [62]: s
Out[62]: [5, 6, 7, 3, 4, 5, 6, 4, 5, 6]

In [63]: [x if i % 2 != 0 else x*2 for i,x in enumerate(s)]
Out[63]: [10, 6, 14, 3, 8, 5, 12, 4, 10, 6]
```

PS [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate):

> **enumerate(sequence, start=0)**
>
> Return an enumerate object. sequence must be a sequence, an iterator, or some other object which supports
> iteration. The next() method of the iterator returned by enumerate()
> returns a tuple containing a count (from start which defaults to 0)
> and the values obtained from iterating over sequence:

Comment: Што такое In , Out и enumerate ???

Comment: Это "prompt" в iPython - интерактивный Python

Answer (score 2):

```
l = [1, 2, 3]
for k, v in enumerate(l):
    if (k+1) % 2 != 0:
        l[k] = v * 2
```

Comment: `(k+1) % 2 != 0` равнозначно `k % 2 == 0`. `L[k] = v * 2` можно заменить на `L[k] *= 2`—в этом случае `enumerate()` не нужен: [`range()` достаточно](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/591872/23044)

Comment: да, вы правы) подумал упадет при получении остатка для нуля